# display entire key/value of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to print out the following arrays:

- The first is a single array
- The following are two arrays stored in a list

  ```
  var ideaGeneration_online_stagea = {

      title: "Entrepreneurial Behaviour",
      outcome: "Open University, free course about entrepreneurship, it's nature and functions and to help you establish a business idea.",
      cost: "",
      duration: "",
      link: "http://www.open.edu/openlearn/money-management/management/business-studies/entrepreneurial-behaviour/content-section-0"

  }

  var ideaGeneration_online_stageb = [
  {

      title: "The serial entrepreneur's guide to startup ideas",
      outcome: "",
      cost:  10.00 ,
      duration: 6,
      link: "https://www.udemy.com/the-step-by-step-guide-to-creating-100mm-startup-ideas/"

  },

  {

      title: "21 critical lessons for entrepreneurs",
      outcome: "",
      cost: "",
      duration: 2,
      link: "https://www.udemy.com/21-golden-rules-for-entrepreneurs/"

  }
  ];

  alert(ideaGeneration_online_stagea);
  alert(ideaGeneration_online_stageb);
  ```

I know that the way I am outputing it using alert is incorrected, and the result I get are:
`[object Object]` for the first and `[object Object], [object Object]` for the second so I am clearly not displaying them properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So based on your comments I'm assuming that you want to combine all the title value in a single string and display it in a page. If it so follow the below,

Add a HTML tag for displaying output

```
<div id="output"></div>
```

Add the following javascript code

```
    var outputString="";
    if(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.length>0) {
       ideaGeneration_online_stagea.forEach(function(item) {
          outputString = outputString + item.title +"<br>"; 
       });
    } else {
        outputString = ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title;
    }
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML=outputString;
```

Answer (score 3):

use `console.log(ideaGeneration_online_stagea)` instead of alert and check your (chrome)developer tools > console tab

Comment: thanks but i want to display it on-screen to the user instead

Comment: `"use console.log"`-> Either that *or* use [stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) ([example](http://jsfiddle.net/99zc4wn6/)). But this is a [BAD IDEA™ either way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32223331/display-entire-key-value-of-arrays#comment52329554_32223347)

Comment: @user3907211: You don't want to use an alert to show a user some json stuff; no-one except developers understand what they're looking at. And the alert will lose formatting/indentation etc. and is limited to a certain text length. This has BAD IDEA™ written all-over it. Better use a modal dialog and format correctly.

Comment: @user3907211: for you have to get all values and set them into string or any html format then you can show them in alert or in modal view etc

Comment: make it a json and print it recursively into a string and put that string into the alert, but i'm in accord with Robll

Comment: as @RobIII mentioned you can show the entire object in front end, create a `div` with id as "test" and use `document.getElementById('test').innerHTML = JSON.stringify(ideaGeneration_online_stagea);` but I am not sure why actaully you want to do so.

Comment: @bipen thanks i am doing this to ensure that my arrays were setup properly

Comment: @bipen what i am only trying to retrieve the value, because with stringify whats displayed is something like {"title":"Entrepreneurial Behaviour","outcome":"Open Univ, where i only want the value of each array key to be shown without the quoation mark or the curly braces

Comment: I am a bit confused about what actaually you need here but you can get values from array with `.` operator so `ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title` gives you the title value you can then have a `div` with title and replace the value.
`Title : <span class="title"></span>` ,
`$('.title').html(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title)` same for others

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code

```
alert(JSON.stringify(ideaGeneration_online_stagea));
alert(JSON.stringify(ideaGeneration_online_stageb ));
```

Use it and let me know if it worked

Comment: thanks what if i am only trying to retrieve the value, because with stringify whats displayed is something like {"title":"Entrepreneurial Behaviour","outcome":"Open Univ, where i only want the value of each array key to be shown without the quoation mark or the curly braces

Comment: @user3907211 If your json is having only one object then you can directly call its property
For Eg

`ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title`

Otherwise use `forEach`

If you are not sure with the size of the array use the length checker

For your Example

`if(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.length>0) {
ideaGeneration_online_stagea.forEach(function(item) {
   alert(item.title); 
});
} else {
    alert(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title);
}`

Answer (score 1):

@user3907211 If your json is having only one object then you can directly call its property
For Eg

```
ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title
```

Otherwise use `forEach`

If you are not sure with the size of the array use the length checker

For your Example

```
if(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.length>0) {
ideaGeneration_online_stagea.forEach(function(item) {
   alert(item.title); 
});
} else {
    alert(ideaGeneration_online_stagea.title);
}
```

Comment: thank you two minor comments. it prints out with the quotation mark such as "title", how do i remove the quotation marks. and my second minor question is how would i print out all of the title of the list of arrays stored in list in ideaGeneration_online_stageb

Answer (score 1):

As Per you discussed to all!

You want to alert the your json based on some thing like key title

here by showed multi ways!

```
alert(JSON.stringify(ideaGeneration_online_stagea));
alert(JSON.stringify(ideaGeneration_online_stageb ));
```

it will return all `json` as a string!!

---

```
var temp = [ideaGeneration_online_stagea,ideaGeneration_online_stageb];

$.each(temp, function(i, val){
    if(val.length){
      for(i=0;i<val.length;i++){        
        $.each(val[i], function(i, value){
            value != ''? alert(value):false;
        });
      }
    }else{
      $.each(val, function(i, value){
            value != ''? alert(value):false;
        });
    }  
});
```

to combine your inputs as a array, then split, it will returns non empty values

```js
  var ideaGeneration_online_stagea = {

title: "Entrepreneurial Behaviour",
outcome: "Open University, free course about entrepreneurship, it's nature and functions and to help you establish a business idea.",
cost: "",
duration: "",
link: "http://www.open.edu/openlearn/money-management/management/business-studies/entrepreneurial-behaviour/content-section-0"

}

var ideaGeneration_online_stageb = [
{

title: "The serial entrepreneur's guide to startup ideas",
outcome: "",
cost:  10.00 ,
duration: 6,
link: "https://www.udemy.com/the-step-by-step-guide-to-creating-100mm-startup-ideas/"

},

{

title: "21 critical lessons for entrepreneurs",
outcome: "",
cost: "",
duration: 2,
link: "https://www.udemy.com/21-golden-rules-for-entrepreneurs/"

}
];

var temp = [ideaGeneration_online_stagea,ideaGeneration_online_stageb];

$.each(temp, function(i, val){
if(val.length){
  for(i=0;i<val.length;i++){        
    $.each(val[i], function(i, value){
        value != ''? alert(value):false;
    });
  }
}else{
  $.each(val, function(i, value){
        value != ''? alert(value):false;
    });
}  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

it will return only title

```
var temp = [ideaGeneration_online_stagea,ideaGeneration_online_stageb];
$.each(temp, function(i, val){
    if(val.length){
      for(i=0;i<val.length;i++){        
        alert(val[i].title);
      }
    }else{
      alert(val.title);
    }  
});
```

```js
  var ideaGeneration_online_stagea = {

title: "Entrepreneurial Behaviour",
outcome: "Open University, free course about entrepreneurship, it's nature and functions and to help you establish a business idea.",
cost: "",
duration: "",
link: "http://www.open.edu/openlearn/money-management/management/business-studies/entrepreneurial-behaviour/content-section-0"

}

var ideaGeneration_online_stageb = [
{

title: "The serial entrepreneur's guide to startup ideas",
outcome: "",
cost:  10.00 ,
duration: 6,
link: "https://www.udemy.com/the-step-by-step-guide-to-creating-100mm-startup-ideas/"

},

{

title: "21 critical lessons for entrepreneurs",
outcome: "",
cost: "",
duration: 2,
link: "https://www.udemy.com/21-golden-rules-for-entrepreneurs/"

}
];

var temp = [ideaGeneration_online_stagea,ideaGeneration_online_stageb];

$.each(temp, function(i, val){
if(val.length){
  for(i=0;i<val.length;i++){        
    alert(val[i].title);
  }
}else{
  alert(val.title);
}  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```